# Assigning Pointers to pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I've encountered a situation where I gotta do some math in a function into a matrix (the dimensions of this are unknown at compile time so I gotta save it as a pointer) and then equate it to a pointer I pass as argument to the function.

The code throws a segmentation fault each time. I have a sample code here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void assign(int **a)
{
  int **A = new int* [3];
  int i, j;

  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    A[i] = new int[3];

  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
      A[i][j] = 100;

  a = A; /* equating the pointers */
}

int main()
{
  int **ptr;
  assign(ptr); /* Passing my pointer into the function */
  cout << ptr[0][0] << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The code is in C++ and it is not an option for me to make the function have a return type other than void. And I don't want to save my matrix on a normal pointer by row/column major - I need to know why this doesn't work.

Comment: @Nidish Have you tried to write the 'assign' function that assigns value to a simple 'int' instead of an 'int**'? Write it in the same way and try to check whether the value before the assignment and after differ in any way - http://denniskubes.com/2012/08/20/is-c-pass-by-value-or-reference/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look carefully at your code:

```
void assign(int** a)
{
    // ...
}

int main()
{
    int** ptr;
    assign(ptr);
}
```

You're passing `a` by value - after calling `assign(ptr)`, you will not modify `ptr` itself inside the function body, but merely a copy of `ptr`.

Take `ptr` by reference instead:

```
void assign(int**& a)
{
    // ...
}
```

---

Other possible solutions:

1. Add another level of indirection.

   ```
   void assign(int*** a)
   {
       // ...
       *a = A;
   }

   int main()
   {
       int** ptr;
       assign(&ptr);
   }
   ```
2. Return from `assign`.

   ```
   int** assign()
   {
       // ...
       return A;
   }

   int main()
   {
       int** ptr;
       ptr = assign();
   }
   ```

Comment: +1. I think that returning `A` from `assign()` is the simplest and best way (no need to worry about passing by value/reference).

Comment: No point in passing `a` into `assign` at all any more. Your last example should be `int** assign()`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: whoops, fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Think about what actually happens in your code in terms of memory. Here's an illustration, taking some imaginary memory addresses for now:

```
    in main():                                 in assign():
ptr at 0x0100, value: garbage_ptr
                                    call
                                   ----->
                                           a at 0x0200, value: garbage_ptr
                                           [after some computation]
                                           A at 0x0204, value: 0x0400
                                           [after the line: a = A;]
                                           a at 0x0200, value: 0x0400
ptr at 0x0100, value: garbage_ptr
```

You can see how nothing is ever written to 0x0100, the address of `ptr`. That's because `a` in `assign()` gets the *value* of `ptr`; it doesn't know *where* `ptr` *is*. `ptr` still points to the untouched (garbage) value that it did when its scope started at the beginning of `main()`.

Suppose, now, that instead change the code to:

```
...
void assign(int ***a)
{
    ...
    *a = A;
}

int main()
{
    int **ptr;
    assign(&ptr);
    ....
```

The above illustration now becomes:

```
    in main():                         in assign():
ptr at 0x0100, value: garbage_ptr
&ptr rvalue, value: 0x0100
                                     call
                                   ----->
                                           a at 0x0200, value: 0x0100
                                           *a at 0x100, value: garbage_ptr
                                           [after some computation]
                                           A at 0x0204, value: 0x0400
                                           [after the line: *a = A;]
                                           a at 0x200, value: 0x0100
                                           *a at 0x100, value: 0x0400
                                   return
                                   <-----
ptr at 0x100, value: 0x0400
```

This way, the value at `0x0100` *does* get changed, which is what you wanted. (Actually, you should use a reference for this kind of thing in C++, but it's easier to show the error with pointers.)